# Passing Variable From Javascript to HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a simple ideal weight counter, i thought the logic is correct but there must be a fault in the codes, can someone show me where is it..? Thank you..

```html
<html>
<body>
  Height (Cm)
  <input type=text id="height"><br>
  <button onClick="Count()">Submit</button><br>
  Ideal Weight (Kg)
  <input type=text id="ideal"><br>
  
  <script>
    function Count()
    {
      var hei = document.getElementById('height').Value;
      var ideal = (hei - 100)- ((hei - 100)*0.1);
      document.getelementById('ideal').value = ideal;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementById`. always read errors.

Comment: so, how to correct it..?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. Input elements don't have a `Value` property and `document` doesn't have a `getelementById` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues:

`var hei = document.getElementById('height').**v**alue;`

and

`document.get**E**lementById('ideal').value = ideal;`

Comment: Nice, I see. then how to input ideal value into the textbox sir..?